# How do I test the Air Tap gesture in Hololens Emulator?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens-emulator

I am building an Augmented Reality app for Hololens. I need to test the Air Tap Gesture, without deploying to the Hololens.

Is there any method to test the Air Tap functionality through the Hololens Emulator or the Holographic Emulation provided by Unity3D?

Comment: I think the Holotool kit takes care of that when using the Hololens Camera and input prefab.

Comment: @Everts i means that when i run my project on Hololens Emulator then how  i will be able to click on button through Air Tap not through mouse click.

Answer (score 3):

This will depend on your emulation environment:

- [**Hololens Emulator**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using_the_hololens_emulator#basic_emulator_input) (From Microsoft, allows multiple input devices)

  > Air tap gesture - Right-click the mouse, press the Enter key on your keyboard, or use the A button on an Xbox controller.
- **[Windows Holographic Emulation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-emulation.html)** (From Unity, requires game controller)

  > Perform a tap gesture with a
  > virtual hand -  Left and right trigger buttons; the A button

Comment: Sometimes it also takes `Space` key on your keyboard in Hololens Emulator (From Microsoft, allows multiple input devices)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answer. If you don't have a HoloLens this will not help but, if you do this will speed up development significantly.

On your HoloLens, download the Holographic Remoting App. Once it is downloaded open and run it and you will see your IP address for your HoloLens.

Now, go to the Unity editor -> Window tab -> Holographic Emulation. This will open a new window. For Emulation mode select remote device. Under Remote Machine enter the IP address. You can tinker with the other settings as you see fit.

Now with the Application running on your HoloLens click connect. Once you are connected the Unity editor will tell you and the HoloLens should go blank. Now when you press play on the editor the app will run on the HoloLens.

**This does not download the app to your HoloLens and stops running when you stop the editor**

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in the Unity editor,

- Shift + LMB (left-mouse-button) to simulate air-tap with the left
  hand;
- Space + LMB to simulate air-tap with the right hand.

Other useful points:

- gaze can be controlled with the mouse by keeping RMB down. Also
  q/w/e/a/s/d. (I know question was only about airtap, but they kind of
  come together).
- If you need to test typing some data with the standard keyboard, no
  need to simulate airtap - just click with the mouse.